# Detect Image in RichTextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I am using a `RichTextBox` control on my form. I want a small code which can detect if any image has been inserted in the rtb or not. (IDE VS 2008)

For e.g. user can just type some text or insert image also (Ctrl + V). Now if we select an image then we can get the type but I want a code which scans contents of rtb and gives me a true if an image is inserted or false if there is none.

Answer (score 4):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Clipboard.SetImage(img)
    RichTextBox1.Paste()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _  
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MsgBox("contains image: " & RichTextBox1.Rtf.Contains("\pict\wmetafile8\"))
End Sub
```

it searches the richtextbox inner code, "\pict\wmetafile8\" is the pic tag.